# AWS QuickSight exporting data

Tags: amazon-quicksight

Is it possible to export my AWS QuickSight data programmatically?

Basically I have my data in AWS QuickSight which I need to extract so I can import it into a third party application. Manually this is easy through the "export" link on QuickSight. But I was wondering if there was a way to do this automatically? Through an API / third party connector / etc?

Answer (score 1):

I am familiar with [QuickSight docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/quicksight/latest/user/amazon-quicksight-user.pdf) and I have not seen a way to export data programmatically inside QuickSight.

There might be a third party connector. Nonetheless, more than often, your QuickSight data source should be easier to access programmatically.

Unless there is a strong reason to use QuickSight export, I will access the data source directly.

Answer (score 0):

There's no direct defined way(an AWS way) to export data programatically from Quicksight visuals. But I did follow certain methods to create a scraper and achieved this. I'm listing out the steps below and I did this using Python.

You need to work with 2 libraries, boto3 & BeautifulSoup(BS).
Boto3 to get Quicksigh.Dashboard.visual details and BS to scrape data.

1. Create a Quicksight Client for programatic access,

```py
import boto3

client = boto3.client('quicksight',
                      region_name='us-east-1',
                      aws_access_key_id='YOUR_ACCESS_KEY',
                      aws_secret_access_key='YOUR_SECRET_KEY',
                      aws_session_token='YOUR_SESSION_TOKEN')
```

Every Visual in a Dashboard will have an identifier, you can get that through embedd visual coontrol, programatically you can call [get_dashboard_embed_url](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/quicksight/client/get_dashboard_embed_url.html) method to get the embed URL for your QuickSight visual

```
response = client.get_dashboard_embed_url(
    AwsAccountId='YOUR_ACCOUNT_ID',
    DashboardId='YOUR_DASHBOARD_ID',
    IdentityType='IAM',
    SessionLifetimeInMinutes=10080,
    UndoRedoDisabled=True,
    ResetDisabled=True,
    SessionTags=[
        {
            'Key': 'string',
            'Value': 'string'
        },
    ],
    AdditionalDashboardIds=[
        'string',
    ],
    ExcludeFilters=False,
    Parameters={
        'string': 'string'
    }
)

embed_url = response['EmbedUrl']
```

we're doing the above step to get the `embed_url`

You can use python's requests library to make a GET request to the embed URL and then parse the HTML response with beautifulsoup4

sample BS code below

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

response = requests.get(embed_url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')

# Your Code Here based on the Table/Visual Structure
```

Please note that

1. you need to fill in your account/aws creds into this
2. you can directly get the visual embedd url from the dashboard manually via dashboard but if you want to automate it programatically, you need to run boto3 to get it
3. I used the same code (excluding some private stuff) to get data from a pivot table and wrote it to Redshift as I do not have DB access and only dashboard access.

Let me know your feedback, if this works !

Comment: I tried it but it's only available to enterprise users..